# How to use date filters in Service Bus Explorer

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am using service bus explorer version 4.1.112. How can I filter by date?
I tried different formats but nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: `TimeGenerated`, is that a custom property on the messages?

Comment: @SeanFeldman Yes, it is custom message property

Answer (score 0):

Filter Expression works by executing a SQL filter. The filter has to follow the Service Bus SQL filter [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-filter). That syntax doesn't support filtering dates.

The example you're providing would select all messages with the custom property `TimeGenerated` with the specific value, `27/07/2021`.